# My Async HTTP-Post does not work for an unkown reason

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, http-post, android-studio

I'm new to android and i try a simple HTTP Post, i had one working but became the error message that you can't post in the main class. After some Google research i found an alternative - the async-task - but I can't completely understand why this simple sample does not work.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

```
      new MyAsyncTask().execute().toString();
        }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {
        // private ProgressBar pb;
         //pb=(ProgressBar);
         //pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {

            postData(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
          //  pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent",   
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

      //  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        //    pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        //}

        public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url(got a real one here)");

try {

// Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

// Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   // Log.i("CATCH Read from server", "error");
    } catch (IOException e) {
   // Log.i("CATCH Read from server", "error");
     }
    }
   }
```

> 11-11 15:08:32.768      357-394/? E/lights﹕ write_int failed to open /sys/class >/sec/sec_touchkey/brightness
>
> 11-11 15:10:45.503      110-259/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger translucent=1 >isOpaque=0 isExternalDisplayLayer=0 isExternalBlockLayer0
>
> 11-11 15:04:57.643  28774-28790/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>      java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>              at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>              at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>              at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in >parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=vlothopc.dyndns-home.com/mobile.asp
>              at >org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.j>ava:591)
>              at >org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293>)
>              at >org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>              at >org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>              at >org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>              at >com.example.miniapp2.MainActivity$1$MyAsyncTask.postData(MainActivity.java:310)
>              at >com.example.miniapp2.MainActivity$1$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:284)
>              at >com.example.miniapp2.MainActivity$1$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:276)
>              at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>               at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>               at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Comment: Any logging? Also, are you sure you're not throwing exceptions?

Comment: do you have internet permission in your mainfest
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: no exception, my application simple stops running. Yes i have the Internet Permission in my Android Manifest. I gonna add the Logcat Traces.

Comment: What's the parameter that passed to AsyncTask.execute()? None?

Answer (score 0):

You have the following exception message in your logs:

```
Target host must not be null, or set in >parameters. scheme=null, host=null
```

This may comes from the host value you put while initializing your HttpPost object. You forgot to specify the protocol i think.

What's the exact value of your URL? Try with 'http://' if not set yet.

You should also specify the content type, length, etc. just not sure this is required as the protocol.

Comment: I decide to use the async task for different reasons, for example it should be safer than a simple http-post. Question is why does this sample not work?

Comment: I added the logcat from debugging on device, it is different from the virtual device - may that help you to help me?

Comment: I'm using the url of an website, so i can check if i successfully send the data or not. How do i specify the content type and length if it would be different in different situation?

Comment: how do i add the protocol? and the other parameters any examples?

Comment: You have to provide URL as String, including the protocol. For example: "http://myweburl.com". And to specify the other header properties for your request, just check properties of object HttpPost, you should have method like 'setHeader('propName', value)'

Comment: Sure ? With 'http ://' at the beginning ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950527/host-setted-still-i-get-the-error-message-target-host-must-not-be-null-http

im just to stupid to make any kind of http post running, changed it @ async still, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute().toString();
//changed to
new MyAsyncTask().execute("value 1");
```

Please always check the length of [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) `String... params`.

Comment: changed it, still it does not work no difference in the logcat

Comment: `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url(got a real one here)");` The url is a fake one?

Comment: its a real url to a website, and it should be able to receive the data and show it to me as well.