# No exception, no error, still i dont recieve the json object from my http post

Tags: java, json, http-post, android-studio

My source code:

```
    final Thread t = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();


            try {
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://pc.dyndns-office.com/mobile.asp");

                obj.put("Model", ReadIn1);
                obj.put("Product", ReadIn2);
                obj.put("Manufacturer", ReadIn3);
                obj.put("RELEASE", ReadIn4);
                obj.put("SERIAL", ReadIn5);
                obj.put("ID", ReadIn6);
                obj.put("ANDROID_ID", ReadIn7);
                obj.put("Language", ReadIn8);
                obj.put("BOARD", ReadIn9);
                obj.put("BOOTLOADER", ReadIn10);
                obj.put("BRAND", ReadIn11);
                obj.put("CPU_API", ReadIn12);
                obj.put("DISPLAY", ReadIn13);
                obj.put("FINGERPRINT", ReadIn14);
                obj.put("HARDWARE", ReadIn15);
                obj.put("UUID", ReadIn16);

                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                post.setHeader("host", "http://pc.dyndns-office.com/mobile.asp");

                response = client.execute(post);

                if (response != null) {
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Looper.loop();
        }
    };

    t.start();
 }
}
```

i want to send an Json object to a Website. As far as I can see, I set the header, but still I get this exception, can someone help me?

(I'm using Android-Studio)
__

Edit: i don't get any exceptions anymore, but still i do not receive the json packet.

When i manually call the website i get a log file entry.

Does anyone know, what's wrong?

Edit2:
When i debug i get as response "HTTP/1.1 400 bad request" i'm sure its not an permission problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is because `pc.dyndns-office.com/mobile.asp` is not valid.

Try `http://pc.dyndns-office.com/mobile.asp`.

Comment: Is the remote host actually up?

Comment: Yes it is, any other ideas?

Comment: I checked it and it is not up for me.

Comment: Now i don't get any exception anymore, but i do not receive the object as well?

well i changed that url slightly, not that someone spams it